# How can I take a input value and put into a variable in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I take a input value and put into a variable in angularJS?
this is the working testing version on my page but I did javascript and jquery together with angularJS to make it work but it is still giving me errors.
I know there must be a way to take the input value and put it inside of a var value through angularJS with out writting it manually how I'm doing it.

http://www.jaysg.com/poster

index.html

```
<div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <h1>Find That Poster</h1>

                        <div class="searchbox">
                            <button ng-click="start()" class="searchButton" id="btnSearch" value="Search">Search</button>
                            <p></p>
                        <input onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

      </div>




      <div class="content" ng-controller="StoreController as store">
        <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
      <div >

        <div class="col-md-3 posterImg" ng-repeat="product in store.products.results">

                    <span><img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300{{product.poster_path}}" class="img-responsive"></span>

                    <div >

              <!-- <h2> {{product.original_title}}</h2>-->




                </div>




      </div>


      </div>
      </div>


            </div>

            </div>
      </div>


            </div>
```

app.js // angular

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('store', ['store-products']);//main app ng-app

    app.controller('StoreController',[ '$http', function($http){

        var store = this;

        store.products = [ ];

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "input" ).keyup(function() {
                    var value = $( this ).val();




            $('button').click(function() {

        $http.get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=2f6ab7c6dc3db52d34703aae308640ef&query=" + value ).success(function(data){

            store.products = data;

        });

    });
                 })
                  .keyup();
        });

                          }]);


    })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the value of the variable  use ng-model and to listen for the key down use ng-keydown

```
<div class="searchbox">
   <button ng-click="search()" class="searchButton" id="btnSearch" value="Search">Search</button>
      <p>
      </p>
      <input ng-keydown="press($event)" ng-model="searchField" >   
 </div>
```

and in your controller you   call the functions you just  bound to your dom elements

```
app.controller('StoreController', [
'$scope',
'$http',
function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.press = function (e) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $scope.search();
        }
    };
     $scope.search = function (e) {
          $http.get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=2f6ab7c6dc3db52d34703aae308640ef&query=" + $scope.searchField )
           .success(function(data){

        $scope.products = data;

    });
    };

}
]);
```

Comment: I copied this into my code an it aint showing up any results of the search.. I guess its coded right because there's no errors but it's not working

Comment: OK>>> Got it working I needed to change the ng-repeat thank you

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 posterImg" ng-repeat="product in products.results">
                  
                    <span><img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300{{product.poster_path}}" class="img-responsive"></span>
                    
                    <div >
                
              <!-- <h2> {{product.original_title}}</h2>-->
              
               
            
                    
                </div>
                
                
            
            
      </div>

Comment: it is working , you can log the $scope.products in the controller and change your html markup accordingly

Comment: Yeah I got it working thank you!!! You the man !! I'm new to angular and for some reason I find the documentation hard to read and understand. It's not like Jquery which seems more easy to read and understand the examples without a computer science degree

Answer (score 2):

You need the `ng-model` attribute.

Example:

```
<input onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()" ng-model="search">
```

Then you can access the variable using `$scope.search`.

As I can see you are currently not injecting the $scope.
This is how to do it:

```
app.controller('StoreController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
```

See more in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

It would also be advisable to rewrite your jquery event handlers to angular event handlers.
So instead of `$('button').click(function() {`, create a `$scope.start()` function that is bound to the click event of the search button.